# Maven multi module project cannot find sibling module

Tags: java, maven, multi-module

I can't seem to get Maven to find a sibling's module in a multi-module project.

I've run `mvn clean install` in all modules.

Here's the setup:

```
Product
+-- MagniCompCommon
+-- Model
```

The `Model` project has `MagniCompCommon` as a dependency.  When I run `mvn clean compile` in `Model`, I get:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Model 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.magnicomp:MagniCompCommon:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.585 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-14T10:09:04-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Model: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.magnicomp:Model:jar:1.0: Failure to find com.magnicomp:MagniCompCommon:jar:1.0 in http://download.java.net/maven/2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Java.Net has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

As you can see, Maven is trying to find `MagniCompCommon` in the java.net repo (this is the first repository entry in the parent (`Product`) `pom.xml`).

Here is Product `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.magnicomp</groupId>
  <artifactId>Product</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>


  <modules>
    <module>MagniCompCommon</module>
    <module>Model</module>
    <module>Common</module>
    <module>Agent</module>
    <module>Doc</module>
  </modules>

... snip ...

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Java.Net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
```

Here is MagniCompCommon `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.magnicomp</groupId>
        <artifactId>Product</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- <groupId>com.magnicomp.common</groupId> -->
    <artifactId>MagniCompCommon</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Here is Model `pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.magnicomp</groupId>
        <artifactId>Product</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>Model</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.magnicomp</groupId>
            <artifactId>MagniCompCommon</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 30):

When you are building a multi-module Maven project, you need to run Maven commands from the root POM. This means you need to run `mvn clean install` on `Product`'s `pom.xml`.

The error you are getting is expected: you are only building `Model`. In `Model`'s POM, Maven sees that there is a dependency on `MagniCompCommon` so it tries to look for that dependency. First, it searches in your local repo: it fails to find it there since you did not install `MagniCompCommon` before. As a result, it looks for it in the predefined remote repositories (and also fails to find it).

You would be able to circumvent this by first running `mvn clean install` on `MagniCompCommon`'s POM, then on `Model` POM but this is much easier done by invoking Maven directly on the root POM. It will correctly build every modules in the right order (since `Model` depends on `MagniCompCommon`, it will build `MagniCompCommon` first, *then* `Model`).

As a side note, you can remove the line `<packaging>jar</packaging>` because this is the default.

Comment: Yes that was the problem!  I need to be in the parent "Product" directory.  Such a newbie error!  Thank you SO much!

Answer (score -2):

I noticed **MagniCompCommon** pom doesnt specify a version

```
<!-- <groupId>com.magnicomp.common</groupId> -->
<artifactId>MagniCompCommon</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

And in **Product** pom, you're referencing version **1.0**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.magnicomp</groupId>
    <artifactId>MagniCompCommon</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Have you tried specifying version **1.0** in MagniCompCommon pom?

Comment: You don't need to specify a version, the module will inherit from the parent's version (1.0 in this case).