# Maven hierarchical dependency search

Tags: maven, maven-reactor

So I have a problem, that is - Maven seems to ignore dependencies, even though they should be visible in hierarchy.

I have following project hierarchy:
parent
--projA
--sub-parent1
----projB
----projC

All levels are linked via `<parent>` tag.
`sub-parent1` has `projB` and `projC` declared as modules and no dependencies declared. But `projB` has a dependency on `projA`. And building entire `sub-parent1` module will not build `projA`, which is strange, because `projB` is aware of `sub-parent1` and `sub-parent1` is aware of `parent` and it is aware of dependency (`projA`). But maven do not build it whenever I build entire `sub-parent1` or, for example, `-pl projB -am clean install`.
Any help appreciated.

Edit:
I've created a structure, representing this structure. Try to build sub-parent: dropmefiles.com/5l42j

Edit:
parent pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>


    <modules>
        <module>projA</module>
        <module>sub-parent1</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

projA:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>projA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

</project>
```

sub-parent1:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>sub-parent1</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <modules>
        <module>projB</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

projB:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>sub-parent1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>projB</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <artifactId>projA</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Edit:
Although I had the same solution as in [Maven multi module project cannot find sibling module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131880/maven-multi-module-project-cannot-find-sibling-module) - this problem is different as it deals with not only with multimodule, but with multilevel (several levels of modules) project and person there did not told maven explicitly to build dependencies aswell.

**Solution:**
So it seems the only solution is - build such multilevel structure from the upper-most level pom, in my case it will be parent (so parent is current dir) and address module you need to build by relative path from the parent. That results in:

```
mvn -pl sub-parent1/projB -am clean install
```

The order will be:

```
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] parent
[INFO] projA
[INFO] sub-parent1
[INFO] projB
```

Comment: Can you post all of your POM? Maybe there's a version mismatch?

Comment: @Tunaki here, I've created a structure, representing this structure. Try to build sub-parent: http://dropmefiles.com/5l42j

Comment: @Tunaki added poms

Comment: You should start the build from `parent` and not from `sub-parent1`, see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/33131999/1743880

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven multi module project cannot find sibling module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131880/maven-multi-module-project-cannot-find-sibling-module)

Comment: Glad I could help. I flagged it as duplicate then. Feel free to accept it so that future visitors are redirected to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the only solution is - build such multilevel structure from the upper-most level pom, in my case it will be parent (so parent is current dir) and address module you need to build by relative path from the parent. That results in:

```
mvn -pl sub-parent1/projB -am clean install
```

The order will be:

```
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] parent
[INFO] projA
[INFO] sub-parent1
[INFO] projB
```