# Maven sibling dependency issue in a multi module project

Tags: java, maven, m2e

I have a multi module project with 1 main module (engine) and 2 sub modules (client and server)

engine (Main module)
  - Client 
  - Server

When I try to use the server module in the client, It throws a compilation error that indicates that the server package was not found.

Please find all the 3 POM's below.

#### Engine POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>dev.kasse</groupId>
<artifactId>engine</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>server</module>
    <module>client</module>
</modules>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

#### Client pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <groupId>dev.kasse</groupId>
    <artifactId>engine</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>client</artifactId>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    **<dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>server</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>**
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>0</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>               
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

#### Server POM

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>dev.kasse</groupId>
        <artifactId>engine</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
  </project>
```

Comment: What Maven commands did you launch and on which project?

Comment: i tried launching with "mvn clean install". I get a compilation error in my eclipse as well.

Comment: You need to launch that command from the parent POM, see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33131999/1743880

Comment: Yes i launched the command from parent POM but still i get the compilation error. I could see the jar file (server) getting added to the client's maven dependencies but still it does shows a compilation error :(

Comment: you launch "mvn clean test" from the parent pom directory, right? Please attach the error message

Comment: Why did you include the dependency in double stars? Is this a failed attempt to highlight it? Or is it really in the code?

Comment: Actually i want to higlight the dependency..its not included in my actual pom

Comment: @Sammyrulez I am using eclipse and i couldn't see server package being resolved in my client. Eclipse also throws a compilation error...

Answer (score 2):

Your modules need

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

to overwrite the

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

from the parent file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...but its still not resolved :(

Comment: Could you please copy and paste the exact error message?

Comment: One additional note...In my client's maven dependency i could see the server jar file with packages from springframework and my server classes are included in BOOT_INF folder. Please let me know whether this is normal...I was expecting server packages as well under thee jar

Comment: The import dev.kasse.engine.server cannot be resolved

Comment: import dev.kasse.engine.server.Application;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class}, webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class CustomerRestClientTest {

Comment: The above one is a client's test case where Application.class is the server class file

Comment: Is dev.kasse.engine.server a class? (Shouldn't class names be upper case)?

Comment: Maven Error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project client: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /D:/Restaurant/workspace/engine/client/src/test/java/dev/kasse/client/test/rest/TicketRestClientTest.java:[20,31] package dev.kasse.engine.server does not exist

Comment: dev.kasse.engine.server is package and Application is the class name

Comment: My complete project is available in https://github.com/deivarayanazhagappan/kasse-engine

May be this could provide you a deeper insight of the problem

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar project set-up, but your solution worked just fine for me.

Still one way that could maybe have solved it in your case, would be to define the version in the **parent pom** using the **dependencyManagment**

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>server</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 1):

The dependency to the server has "test" scope: this means that is will be not included in the runtime package

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope> <!-- remove this tag -->
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

for more information on dependency scopes see: [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)

Comment: Thank you for your reply..I am using the server dependency in my client for only JUnit test cases. I dont need it for my client application. But even removing it does not solve the problem :(

Answer (score 1):

Ran into  a similar problem. This seems to be caused by spring boots' packaging of jar. The Spring boot create an executable jar, sending the classes into BOOT-INF folder inside the jar.

Adding the following into the build\plugins section of the pom resolves the issue (client pom in the case here)

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <forceCreation>true</forceCreation>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

An alternative solution is here : [Maven Multi-module dependency package not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740349/maven-multi-module-dependency-package-not-found)