# Intellij maven module inheritence

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have gone through the documentation, but still not able to achieve what I am trying to. The requirement is very simple. I have two maven projects. **ProjectA** and **ProjectB**. **ProjectB** requires to reuse some common configs and code from **ProjectA**. I don't want to just copy and paste them as this is will require to updates if anything changes. So, what are the options now? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a silver bullet for this but we use combination of these two aproaches:

1. Multi-module project (best if projects are connected and you want to change common parts a lot): https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html
2. Extract parts you want to reuse from projectA and make it a standalone artifact which you publish to maven repo (local/private/public - depending on your use case).

Answer (score 1):

You might have two options.

- Use your **ProjectA** has parent of your **projectB**

  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      4.0.0

  ```
  <parent>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>

     <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
  ```

  Thus, your **projectB** will inherit from the first one, with all its dependencies build / dependency management.
- Use your **ProjectA** has dependency of your **projectB**

  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      4.0.0

  ```
     <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ```

In this case, **projectB** wil inherit from **projectA** all the sources and dependencies.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info. The first approach did not work. Adding module as dependency worked, but when I run mvn install, it says  package com.email.model does not exist, which is available at compile time in intellij.

Answer (score 0):

I created a multi module maven project but it was always compiling that the packages not found. Eventually, I figured out the issue here. [Maven Multi-module dependency package not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740349/maven-multi-module-dependency-package-not-found)

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <classifier>exec</classifier>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```