# Is it necessary to install maven submodule dependencies before building the client submodule?

Tags: maven

Given

```
   <modules>
      <module>A</module>
      <module>B</module>
    </module>
   </modules>
```

in a parent `pom.xml`.  And in `B/pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Then - what is the process here?  It feels "wrong" to need to do

```
   mvn -pl A  clean package install
```

and then

```
   mvn  -pl B clean package
```

in order to get the A dependency of B available before building the latter.  It seems maven should know how to sort this out.  What am I missing?

**Update** In response to (good) questions from @Tunaki

Both A and B have :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.myco.mypkg</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
```

And the GAV is correct for A and also correctly referenced in B

```
<groupId>org.myco.mypkg</groupId>
<artifactId>A</artifactId>
<name>Name of A</name>
<version>1.0.0</version>
```

Comment: I don't understand. Maven already sorts this correctly with just running `mvn clean install` from the parent project. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131880/maven-multi-module-project-cannot-find-sibling-module

Comment: @Tunaki So it appears the issue were that i had done only `mvn clean package` ?  There is a related issue:  `Intellij` "rebuild project" only does `mvn clean package` not `mvn package install` .. So i will need to remember only to perform that from command line.

Comment: No, `clean package` or `clean install` should both work. But make sure your multi-module project is really correct, i.e.: each module inherit the parent, and the GAV coordinates used in the dependency are the right ones.

Comment: @Tunaki  I double checked and seems things correct: updated OP.