# Failed to execute goal on project XXXX Could not resolve dependencies for project XXXX (sibling module cases)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, war

[Here is my file structure in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnkpK.png)

What I want to do ?

I want include sibling modules into my spring boot project which called AccountManagementSystem

I do not have setting.xml in my  `.m2`  directory

What I have tried

1.Delete `.m2` directory but do not work for me

2. run `mvn clean install -U`  still do not work for me

Here is my error message

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------< com.AccountManagementSystem:AccountManagementSystem >---------
[INFO] Building AccountManagementSystem 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/EncapsulationSystem/EncapsulationSystem/1.0/EncapsulationSystem-1.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.EncapsulationSystem:EncapsulationSystem:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jc/adwords-encapsulation/1.0/adwords-encapsulation-1.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for jc:adwords-encapsulation:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/PermissionSystemApiTool/PermissionSystemApiTool/0.0.1/PermissionSystemApiTool-0.0.1.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.PermissionSystemApiTool:PermissionSystemApiTool:jar:0.0.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/EncapsulationSystem/EncapsulationSystem/1.0/EncapsulationSystem-1.0.jar
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/PermissionSystemApiTool/PermissionSystemApiTool/0.0.1/PermissionSystemApiTool-0.0.1.jar
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jc/adwords-encapsulation/1.0/adwords-encapsulation-1.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.800 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-11-15T16:47:06+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project AccountManagementSystem: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.AccountManagementSystem:AccountManagementSystem:war:0.0.1: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.EncapsulationSystem:EncapsulationSystem:jar:1.0, jc:adwords-encapsulation:jar:1.0, com.PermissionSystemApiTool:PermissionSystemApiTool:jar:0.0.1: Could not find artifact com.EncapsulationSystem:EncapsulationSystem:jar:1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.AccountManagementSystem</groupId>
    <artifactId>AccountManagementSystem</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>AccountManagementSystem</name>
    <description>Account Management System</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.EncapsulationSystem</groupId>
            <artifactId>EncapsulationSystem</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jc</groupId>
            <artifactId>adwords-encapsulation</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.32.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.PermissionSystemApiTool</groupId>
            <artifactId>PermissionSystemApiTool</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.amven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have find some solution

[Maven multi module project cannot find sibling module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131880/maven-multi-module-project-cannot-find-sibling-module)

[Maven Could not resolve dependencies, artifacts could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650460/maven-could-not-resolve-dependencies-artifacts-could-not-be-resolved)

but when i run `mvn clean install`

I got error message

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------< com.AccountManagementSystem:AccountManagementSystem >---------
[INFO] Building AccountManagementSystem 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.EncapsulationSystem:EncapsulationSystem:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for jc:adwords-encapsulation:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.PermissionSystemApiTool:PermissionSystemApiTool:jar:0.0.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.912 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-11-15T16:58:46+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project AccountManagementSystem: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.AccountManagementSystem:AccountManagementSystem:war:0.0.1: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.EncapsulationSystem:EncapsulationSystem:jar:1.0, jc:adwords-encapsulation:jar:1.0, com.PermissionSystemApiTool:PermissionSystemApiTool:jar:0.0.1: com.EncapsulationSystem:EncapsulationSystem:jar:1.0 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

I sequentially run `mvn intall` on my sibling project which solve my problem

or just export project to war file solve my problem because my project is packaging by war